# showing two topologies are identical

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topology and $C(X)$ denote the set of continuous function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathcal{W}$ be the weakest topology on $X$ that makes $f\in C(X)$ continuous, and show if $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is Normal then the two topologies are identical.

So, I am not too sure about what does it means for topologies to be identical here, the book didn't give much info on that and google comes up with different results. I am assuming I need to show that $\mathcal{T}\subset\mathcal{W}$ and $\mathcal{W}\subset\mathcal{T}$. By definition of $C(X)$ and $\mathcal{W}$, $\mathcal{W}\subset\mathcal{T}$ is trivial.
But I'm basically stuck on this for a while now, not seeing any connection between $(X,\mathcal{T})$ being a normal space can help.

Any hints or helpful ideas that can help me see the bigger picture about this would be appreciated!

Comment: Urysohn's Lemma should give the opposite inclusion.

Comment: I guess you mean "makes **all** $f \in C(X)$ continuous."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, I am not too sure about what does it means for topologies to be identical here

It literally means they are identical, i.e. $\mathcal{W}=\mathcal{T}$ as sets.

For that we need to show two inclusions. The first one "$ \mathcal{W}\subseteq\mathcal{T}$" is always true. Indeed, assume that $U\in\mathcal{W}$. By the definition of $\mathcal{W}$ there are continuous (in $\mathcal{T}$) maps $f_i:X\to\mathbb{R}$ and open subsets $V_i\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that $U=\bigcup_i f_i^{-1}(V_i)$. Therefore $U\in\mathcal{T}$.

Now assume that $\mathcal{T}$ is normal. We will show that $\mathcal{T}\subseteq\mathcal{W}$. Let $F$ be a closed subset in $\mathcal{T}$. Since $\mathcal{T}$ is normal, then for any $x\in X\backslash F$ there is continuous (in $\mathcal{T}$) $f_x:X\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_x(F)=\{0\}$ and $f_x(x)=1$. This is a consequence of [the Urysohn's lemma.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma) Of course $f_x^{-1}(0)$ may be bigger than $F$, but $F=\bigcap_{x\in X\backslash F}f_x^{-1}(0)$ showing that $F$ is closed in $\mathcal{W}$.